# "Warning: Combine this with the previous 'var' statement", while the variable spoken of is after a for loop

Tags: javascript, jslint

So I have this bit of code:

```
function circular() {
    "use strict";
    var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("loadingCircle"),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < circle.length; i += 1) {
        var radius = circle[i].getAttribute("data-radius"),
            trackWidth = circle[i].getAttribute("data-trackWidth"),

            // more after this but it's not relevant
```

Now I do get this JSlint warning:

> Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.

But if I would do that the whole script would be killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variables `radius` and `trackWidth` outside of the for loop, without assigning them in the head of the function, like this:

```
function circular() {
    "use strict";
    var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("loadingCircle"),
        radius,
        trackWidth,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < circle.length; i += 1) {
        radius = circle[i].getAttribute("data-radius"),
        trackWidth = circle[i].getAttribute("data-trackWidth"),

            // more after this but it's not relevant
```

As an aside, JSLint is notoriously strict, and many of its rules are more stylistic preferences. You may prefer to use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) instead (and plugins for many editors are also available)

Comment: The reasoning being that the variables are then initialized only once, and not once per loop cycle.